# php jsonp with angularjs $http problems

Tags: php, angularjs

I tried to set up a communication between server-child and server-mother.

The record.html in server-mother would display the data fetched via output.php at server-child. The code is what I found in the tutorial on the net.

But nothing shows, please give me some hint.Thanks.

Following is the code
**server-mother record.html**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="controller1">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in list">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>  
</body>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('controller1', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.jsonp( 'http://xxxxx.server-child.com/output.php').then( function ( response ) {
        $scope.list = response.list;
    });
});
</script>
```

**server-child output.php**

```
<?php header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$data['list'] = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($data).')';

?>
```

Comment: Your server needs warp the JSON response with the callback function. Are you sure your server is doing the right thing ? It needs to get from the query the name of the wrapper function.

Comment: could you kindly show an revised code with the wrapper function you mentioned?Thanks.

Comment: I had add one line: $callback = isset($_GET["callback"])?$_GET["callback"]:"callback"; in the php , but it failed again.

Comment: You URL xxx.php should contain this xxx.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK, Angular will dynamically give the callback a name, and on PHP side, you get the name from $_GET['callback'] and use it to wrap the JSON result object

Comment: still no response.http://plnkr.co/edit/zcKCC6uxLgUeUJUFfEVr

Answer (score 0):

Change you code like this because ajax always return JSON or JSON Array

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('controller1', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get( 'http://xxxxx.server-child.com/output.php').success( function ( response ) {
        $scope.list = response.list;
    });
});
```